# Save data to database before viewcontroller deallocated

Tags: ios, swift, deinit

I have a viewcontroller showing the detail of a book. What I want to do is saving data to database in a background thread before the viewcontroller is poped from the navigationcontroller.

I don't know where to put the logic save data to database, `viewWillDisappear` or `deinit` are the right choices?

Comment: Yeah, because I save data to database on mainthread can block my UI. Is there any way to keep viewcontroller alive until saving data is completed?

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to create a global service which call to do anything you want to save. Then call it with data in your `viewDidDisappeared()`